# Create new Android Virtual Device Visual Studio 2017

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017, android-virtual-device

Tried to create new AVD from Visual Studio 2017 in the following steps:

- Click Tools and then Android
- And then Android Emulator Manager
- AVD Manager opens up.
- Then I click on Create button.
- Create a new AVD pop up opens.
- I fill fields, AVD Name, Device, Target.

When I am trying to select CPU/ABI, it doesn't give me option of selecting '**Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)**

Environment:
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017 '15.6.6'

Attaching screenshot Below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Open up the `Android SDK Manager` and within the `Platforms` check to see if any of the emulator images installed are the ones labeled with `Google APIs Intel.....` within the API that you need.

Comment: @SushiHangover, Yes I am able to see those labels. I have updated my answer with screenshot.

Comment: Try a Nexus 5/5X instead of the N9 Lollipop tablet

Comment: Upgrade your Android SDK Tools and use the new AVD Manager - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/xamarin-device-manager?tabs=vswin

Comment: @JonDouglas, Thanks thats solve my problem. Can you add your comment as answer, I will accept it.